# Why my php if cycle is not working properly

Tags: php

I have this php code it does a test and run it if the test result is true. But even if it gets a false result CastResult is ignoring the if check.

```
private function canVote($user,$id)
 {
        $userVoted = VoteModel::where('user',$user)->where('post',$id)->get();
        if(count($userVoted)==0)
            {
                $canVote=true;
            }
        else {
            $canVote=false;
        }
      return $canVote;
  }
    private function castVote($mode)
    {
        $user = Auth::getUser();
        $id = $this->param('id');

        if($this->canVote($user,$id))
        {
            $newVote = new VoteModel;
            $newVote->user = $user['name'];
           //other stuff

        } else
            {
                Flash::error('Err');
            }
    }
```

Comment: what is `CastVesult` ??

Comment: Sorry mistyped, fixed it

Comment: ok, now it is `CastResult` which is also not visible ... ?

Answer (score 0):

more simple and clear and no undefined variables:

```
private function canVote($user,$id)
{
    $userVoted = VoteModel::where('user',$user)->where('post',$id)->get();
    return ( count($userVoted) === 0 );
}
```